# Remove leading characters and zero in swift

Tags: swift

I tried to remove some characters from `string` in Swift 4, says: I have

`QC00012345`, return `12345`

`QC00009876`, return `9876`

`QC12345678`, return `12345678`

removing first two characters and those leading zeros.

I looked around in here, people are just using `dropFirst` then convert 
`String` into `Int` then convert it back to `String`.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and `dropFirst`:

```
let str = "QC00009876"
let clean = str.dropFirst(2).replacingOccurrences(of: "^0*", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The expression `^0*` means "zero or more `0` characters at the start of the string".

Or with just a regular expression:

```
let str = "QC00009876"
let clean = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "^..0*", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The expression `^..0*` means "any two characters followed by zero or more `0` characters at the start of the string".

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use `drop(while:)`:

```
let test = "QC00012345"
let num = test.dropFirst(2).drop { $0 == "0"}
```

---

You can also create a `ClosedRange<String>` and use it as predicate if you don't want to drop first two characters manually:

```
let num = test.drop { !("1"..."9" ~= $0) }
print(num)   //  12345
```

or check if a string from 1 to 9 does not contain the character:

```
let num = test.drop { !"123456789".contains($0) }
```

edit/update:

**Swift 5 or later**

Using the Character property [isWholeNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127020-iswholenumber)

```
let num = test.drop { !$0.isWholeNumber || $0 == "0" }
```